# How to setCustomValidity on radio input immediately before form submission

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to `setCustomValidity` on an input immediately before the form is submitted. This seems like the logical approach:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var button = e.currentTarget.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
  button.setCustomValidity('You did it wrong.');
  console.log(button.willValidate);  // true
  console.log(button.checkValidity());  // false
  // Open Dev Tools to see output
  debugger;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="radio">
    <input id="radio" type="radio">
    Radio button
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Despite setting a custom error, the form continues to submit. Is there some other event I need to handle, something that happens *before* the browser decides it's done dealing with validation?

I realize I could use the `required` attribute. The above approach may be better for when:

1. for whatever reason you can edit JavaScript but not the HTML
2. you just want to set a customized error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [reportValidity()](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-cva-reportvalidity):

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // prevent the default action first
  e.preventDefault();

  var button = e.currentTarget.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');

  button.setCustomValidity('You did it wrong.');
  button.reportValidity();
  //console.log(button.willValidate);  // true
  //console.log(button.checkValidity());  // false
  // Open Dev Tools to see output
  //debugger;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="radio">
    <input id="radio" type="radio">
    Radio button
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Validity isn't checked in the `submit` event because, by design, `submit` is not fired if the form is invalid - [the `invalid` event is fired instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit). Therefore you have to manually stop the `submit` event and force re-validation (or at least reporting of the validation).

Comment: I like it, thanks! Holding off accepting in case someone can add an explanation for _why_ validity isn't reported in the `submit` event handler. If nothing comes up, I'll gladly take the working solution and run.  :-)

Comment: Usually you have to check the validity before using `setCustomValidity()` and since  `checkValidity()` doesn't trigger the form validation `reportValidity()` does. see [this](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/report-validity/)

Comment: Right, but submitting the form should trigger form validation, regardless of how validity is set.

Comment: It does, but you need to trigger the UI first.

Comment: I'm not explaining myself well. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erdbxo0v/). If you set custom validity before the `submit` event, it's respected. If you set it during the `submit` event, it's ignored. I understand the report must be triggered. I don't understand why I need to manually trigger the validity report when it's already being triggered by my clicking the `submit` button. i.e. I'm trying to understand the sequence of events involved in form validation.

Comment: I see your point, because when you click on a form submit that does not pass validation, it triggers an [invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid) event instead of `submit` event. Now, If you click again you it will trigger the next event which is `submit` event.